# PNG files and GIMP

Tags: macos, mac, gimp

I have a Mac and I am getting grey squares when I open png files with GIMP. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

grey squares are there so you could recognize when the png image is transparent. grey squares represent the transparent part of an image. it shouldn't bother you, it's normal (and useful actually because you can imediately see the difference between the real image background and no background at all)